# How do threads copy arguments to their own memory space?

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory, concurrency, move

My first question is about regular functions

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <functional>

void print() {
    std::cout << "Function Value Thread running" << std::endl;
}
void printPtr() {
    std::cout << "Print Ptr Thread running" << std::endl;
}
void printToBind() {
    std::cout << "binding" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    // case 1
    std::thread functionValue{print};
    functionValue.join();
    // case 2
    std::thread functionPointerThread{&printPtr}; 
    functionPointerThread.join();
    // case 3
    std::thread withArgs{std::bind(&printToBind)};
    binding.join();
    return 0;
}
```

In case 1, did the thread copy the whole function value into its own memory space?

In case 2, did the thread copy just a pointer to its own memory space? When invoking the function, is it still invoking a function in the main thread's memory space?

In case 3, is it the same underneath behavior as we seen in case 2?

My second question is about function members. I have the following code.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <functional>
class MyClass {
public: 
    MyClass () {std::cout << "constructor" << std::endl;}
    ~MyClass() {std::cout << "destructor" << std::endl;}
    MyClass (const MyClass& myClass) {std::cout << "copy constructor" << std::endl;}
    MyClass (MyClass&& myClass) {std::cout << "move constructor" << std::endl;}
    void print() {
        std::cout << "Function Member Thread Running" << std::endl;
    }
};
int main() {
    // case 1
    {
        std::thread functionMemberThread{&MyClass::print, MyClass()}; 
        functionMemberThread.join();
    }
    std::cout << "------------------" << std::endl;
    // case 2
    {
        MyClass myClass;
        std::thread functionMemberThread{std::bind(&MyClass::print, &myClass)}; 
        functionMemberThread.join();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My questions are

1. In case 1, Was the temporary value `MyClass()` moved into the new thread's memory space? So in the new thread's whole life time, will this object always be valid?
2. In case 2, Have we just copied a pointer into the new thread's memory space? In this case if for any reason `MyClass myClass;` has been released, will the new thread have undefined behavior?

If I run the program above by using

```
$ g++ -std=c++17 main.cpp -o prog -lpthread
$ ./prog
constructor
move constructor
move constructor
destructor
destructor
Function Member Thread Running
destructor
------------------
constructor
Function Member Thread Running
destructor
```

Can anyone help me to understand why the move constructor have been called twice? And why the destructor have been called twice before the thread running? My understanding is that if everything was moved, nothing shall be needed to be destroyed.

Thank you so much!!

Comment: All threads that are running in the same process share the same memory space.

Comment: There are a lot of questions in one, which makes it difficult to answer. Try to focus your questions on one thing at a time.

Comment: Threads don't have "their own memory space." The _hardware_ on which the threads are running probably has _[cache memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_(computing))_ where each CPU keeps a local copy of parts of the shared memory space, but "cache" is not part of the higher-level language description. The cache is abstracted into the concept of [_synchronization_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronization_(computer_science)#Data_synchronization) in which threads are expected to do certain things before and/or after accessing shared data to ensure that they all agree on the values.

Comment: `std::thread functionValue{print}` is equivalent to `std::thread functionValue{&print}` is equivalent to `std::thread functionValue{&&print}` is equivalent to... ad infinitum. They all pass the address of the function.

Comment: Much of this is implementation dependent. I get one move constructor call in **case 1** of the `MyClass` example, not two. You're guaranteed to get *at least one* move / copy constructor call, as the documentation clearly defines that the new thread of execution will call `decay_copy` on all its arguments, and it clearly defines what `decay_copy` does (copies or moves said arguments). If your implementation is making more move constructor calls, it might have to do with the INVOKE implementation, or with the way it accesses the arguments on the new thread stack to call `std::invoke`

Comment: Note: I ran it on a custom Arch Linux distro with g++ version 10.2.0, and `g++ -pthread file.cpp`